# Bind mouse buttons to switch between windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management, mouse

I just bought a new mouse with more buttons than my old one. While they work fine and I can navigate back and forth with the thumb buttons, I would like to know if I can somehow change thumb buttons so that I can switch between windows (basically like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

I took a look at "xbindkeys", but it does not do what I am looking for, since I had no option to add <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the mouse button:8.

As a bonus: would it be possible to assign different shortcuts per app?

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer to your question, but maybe you can find suggestions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons/308969#308969

Comment: Thanks mazienho, that as exactly what I was looking for. I will edit my question, so that it shows the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Please add an answer, and mark this answer as "accepted", so that the question does not show up in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: I have removed "SOLVED" from the title (and also the answer from the question text). Instead of writing *solved*, StackExchange uses "accepted answers", [you can read more about it here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). In short: Click the checkmark under the answer which solves your problem and is most helpful. Only the person asking the question can do this.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wanted to remove it but I forgot. And thanks for spotting and changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I did install xbindkeys, I did not install xautomation, which allowed me to automate and assign key combinations like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. For a detailed explanation, you can follow the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons/308969#308969) posted by mazienho which gives a good example how xbindkeys and xautomation are working together. In order to achieve what I was looking for, I added the following lines to my .xbindkeysrc file:

```
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Tab' 'keyup Alt_L'"  
b:8
```